# How to click Onclick Javascript form using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my source code :

```
<div class="emph a-center addCard"
Or 
<a class="add-link" href="javascript:;" onclick="gotoPaymentAddressForm()">Add a New Credit Card</a
</div>
```

I need to click "Add New Credit" card which open form on the same page. Unable to do this using Selenium.

Kindly advice.

Comment: Please share the html code and what you tried

Comment: Hi Vaibhav,
Did you find the solution for this issue?
I am also having the same issue.Kindly let me know if you have the working solution.
Provided answers have not worked for me till now.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49103753/how-to-run-javascript-using-rselenium/49103876#49103876

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with following:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add a New Credit Card")).click();
```

Comment: In my case, the source code is `<a href="javascript:;" onclick="openLocation('L_52')"> == $0`. But when I do `driver.findElement(By.linkText(" == $0")).click()`, it returns an error saying `no such element: Unable to locate element`. Any help?

Answer (score 5):

You can also use following xpath codes:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@onclick='gotoPaymentAddressForm()']")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Add a New Credit Card')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS selector is faster than XPATH so you can try

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.add-link")).click();
```