# How to click Onclick from <a without text Javascript form using Selenium?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, onclick

This is my source code :

```
<a onclick="pd(event);" tabindex="0" issprite="true" data-ctl="Icon" 

style="overflow: hidden; background: transparent 

url("webwb/pygridicons_12892877635.png!!.png") no-repeat scroll 0px top; width: 

16px; height: 16px;" name="ManageStakeholder_pyWorkPage_202" 

title="Add a data " data-click="[["doGridAction",

[":event","INSERTAFTER"]],["refresh", ["thisSection","", "", "&=", "", 

",",":event","","pyWorkPage"]]]" data-hover="[["changeStyle",

[":event","background-position:0px -16px;", "1"]]]" 

onmouseover="pega.c.cbe.processBehavior(event, "data-hover")"></a>
```

I need click to image (pygridicons_12892877635.png). I using Selenium with chromewebdriver and I look at the selection OK but the onclick from "a" HTML balise do not detected the click.

I see this: [How to click Onclick Javascript form using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23426350/how-to-click-onclick-javascript-form-using-selenium) The solution is click to the text `<a ...> text </a>` but in my case I do not have any text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution by javascript execution (from java):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;

String xpath = "//table[@param_name='SubSectionManage~pzLayout_3']//a[@title='Add a data ']";

((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("document.evaluate(\"" + xpath + "\", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click();");
```

> In this example the xpath is the normal xpath. The important element
>   is **executeScript** (in java) and **document.evaluate** (in javascript).