# How to run javascript using RSelenium?

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I am trying to click an input object on a webpage using a JS call.
First, I'm using RSelenium to pull up the page:

```
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(port = 4444L, verbose = FALSE)
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$navigate('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g293913-d306432-Reviews-Ambassador_Hotel_Taipei-Taipei.html')
```

From the page I'm trying to click on the button "All languages" from the menu below:

[image]

I was trying to trigger the click with a call to JS, which works when running the `script` in the chrome console

```
script <- "document.getElementById('filters_detail_language_filterLang_ALL').click();"
remDr$executeScript(script, args=list())
```

But I get the following error:

> remDr$executeScript(script, args = list())
>
> Selenium message:unknown error: 'args' must be a list   (Session info:
>   chrome=64.0.3282.186)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540469
>   (1881fd7f8641508feb5166b7cae561d87723cfa8),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.4
>   x86_64)
>
> Error:     Summary: UnknownError       Detail: An unknown server-side error
>   occurred while processing the command.     Further Details: run
>   errorDetails method

Answer (score 2):

There may be a bug in RSelenium as such.

Try passing an dummy argument in the list method .

Use this:

```
remDr$executeScript(script, args = list("fugazi"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
element = remDr$findElement(using='xpath','//*
[@id="filters_detail_language_filterLang_ALL"]')
script <-"document.getElementById('filters_detail_language_filterLang_ALL').click();"
remDr$executeScript(script, args=list(element))
```